# ElasticSearch template mustahce

Tags: elasticsearch, templates, mustache

I am trying to iterate through a multidimensional param in an ElasticSearch Mustache template, but my code is not working. Given the following Elastic query with param `att`:

```
GET my_idx/_search/template
{
  "id": "my_template",
  "params": {    
   "att" : [
      {"code":"epi", "values" :  [{ "value":"glove"}, {"value":"hat","lastValue":true}]},
      {"code":"color", "values": [{"value":"Black"}, {"value":"White", "lastValue":true},
                           "last":true}
    ]
  }
}
```

I would like to filter using the `att` param first and then the `values` section. Below is my code, which is not working. Can someone please help me identify what is wrong:

```
{{#att}}
{
   "bool" :
   {
      "should" : [
         {{#values}}
         {
            "nested": {
               "path": "nestedField",
               "query": {
                  "bool": {
                     "must": [
                        {"match": {"att.value": "{{value}}"}},
                        {"match": {"att.code": "{{../code}}"}}]
                  }
               }
            }
         }
         {{^lastValue}}, {{/lastValue}}
         {{/values}}
      ]
   }
}{{^last}}, {{/last}}
{{/att}}
```

Thank you for your help.

UPDATE : If I try this : (thanks to https://codepen.io/johnsonshara/pen/mPzbBO

```
  var data = {
      "Subject": "Template Engines",
      "attributs": [{
              "code": "enduction",
              "values": [{
                      "value": "Paume et doigts"
                  }, {
                      "value": "Non Enduit",
                      "lastValue": true
                  }
              ]
          }, {
              "code": "coloris",
              "values": [{
                      "value": "Noir"
                  }, {
                      "value": "Blanc",
                      "lastValue": true
                  }
              ],
              "last": true
          }
      ]
  };
```

and it works with this template :

```
 <h1>{{Subject}}</h1>
<ul>
{{#attributs}}
    <li>{{code}}
    <ul>{{#values}}
      <li>{{code}} => {{value}}{{^lastValue}}, {{/lastValue}}</li>
        {{/values}}
   </ul>
         {{^last}}, {{/last}}
    </li>
{{/attributs}}
</ul>
```

Why not in my elasticsearch mustache template ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved my problem :

```
{{#att}}
{
   "bool" :
   {
      "should" : [
         {{#values}}
         {
            "nested": {
               "path": "nestedField",
               "query": {
                  "bool": {
                     "must": [
                        {"match": {"att.value": "{{value}}"}},
                        {"match": {"att.code": "{{../code}}"}}]
                  }
               }
            }
         }
         {{^lastValue}}, {{/lastValue}}
         {{/values}}
      ]
   }
}{{^last}}, {{/last}} <---- delete this (in my special case)
{{/att}}
```